# What is the purpose of traiffiqtype param of MS TTS cognitive service URL

Tags: android

I am developing an android application, where I want to integrate   Microsoft TTS cognitive service SDK.
I have found one sample project from 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/blob/master/Android/Sample/speechsdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/speech/tts/TtsServiceClient.java .
Found TTS url is as https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1?traffictype=AndroidTest .
Now my question is: 
1. What is the purpose of traffictype param within above TTS url(as I could not find any documentation)
2. 'traffictype=AndroidTest' is it okay for production url?